# Calling Twitter's API with jsonp dataType will throw a 400 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter, jsonp

When trying to perform an API call to Twitter, I noticed I must use "jsonp" to bypass the cross-domain problem. Using "json" dataType will throw a 400 "Control-Allow-Origin" error.

On the other hand, when I'm switching to jsonp I'm always receiving a 400 error with the following message:

> jquery.min.js:4 GET
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?callback=aloha&q=dog

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here and how to get it fixed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function aloha(result) {
        debugger;
    };
    var twitter_call = $.getJSON({
             type: 'GET',
             contentType: 'application/javascript',
             dataType: 'jsonp',
             cache: true,
             jsonpCallback: 'aloha',
             url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json',
             crossDomain: true,
             headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer MY_BEARER_TOKEN"
             },
             data: {
                "q":"dog"
             }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I just noticed that changing the token I'm using to anything else will throw the exact same error, so it seems like Twitter believes my token is invalid. On the other hand, if I run the exact same call with cURL, Postman or any other REST client everything works perfectly fine using that token, and does not work when changing the token. Hope this helps on the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is officially unsupported by Twitter as mentioned by their team on this topic I raised on their development forum:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-401-problems-with-jsonp-token-with-twitter-rest-api-ajax/73618

Any workarounds found for this topic will be posted directly in that link.