# jQuery Ajax call to twitter API not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm attempting to get a bearer token for my application from the twitter oauth proccess using an ajax call.  When I run the code below I get a 'GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?callback=jQueryXXX_XXX&grant_type=client_credentials&_XXX 400 (Bad Request)' error in my console, where xxx replaces long strings of numbers.

I meticulously followed the instructions in the Twitter documentation, so I'm fairly confident that I've encoded my key correctly but I'm not certain of my syntax since I don't have much programming experience and they don't supply any examples of this method.

Oddly to the error seems to contain some sort of response, but it's not the JSON object promised from a successful request.

I'm hoping someone with more experience will see this and immediately recognize my error.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + secretkey64)
        },  
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Does Twitter provide a JSONP wrapper? Can't see one here ~ https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Twitter's API with jsonp dataType will throw a 400 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338836/calling-twitters-api-with-jsonp-datatype-will-throw-a-400-error)

Comment: I guess the main problem is that you're making a GET request instead of POST (JSONP **only** works via GET), hence the *"bad request"*

Comment: It's a post request.  See type 'POST' in the code.  Also fails with the following errors when JSONP is replaced with JSON.

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400."

Comment: "OPTIONS https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ twitfeed.js:12
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2"

Comment: @Phil  This does appear to be duplicate and unsupported by twitter though. I'll have to do some more learning and find another solution. Thanks for your help.